# Delete all rows of CSV file except rows that contain a specific string

Tags: php, csv, strip

I have a CSV file with over 135,000 products in.
I am trying to import the file into my software but the file is too big.

I need to strip out all the products/rows unless the row contains a specific sku in the script or even better if it can call the data externally.

There will be multiple sku's/rows I need to keep and then I need to save the output back to CSV

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP? Just use something like sed.

Comment: Great, how would I go about using sed for my needs?